# My 18 month old keeps pulling the couch cushions off the pullout sofa - how to keep him safe?

Tags: toddler, safety

We have a couch that has a pull out bed for guests. My son's newest habit (18 months old) is pulling up the cushions and running across where the pull out bed is. We just bought this couch (too expensive to replace), and I am scared to death he is going to break an ankle or get a big gash from running across the exposed but put away pull out bed and falling into the parts where the metal that keeps the pullout bed folded into the couch is. Any suggestions to help me make this safer for him?

Comment: See the answers here, there are a few great suggestions
https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/43995/toddler-keeps-lifting-mattress-up-and-putting-his-legs-into-the-mattress-rack